# How to put an event in dynamic creation on flex?

Tags: apache-flex, events

Please help. I want to add a click event on checkbox that i created dynamically so that i know what checkbox I click.

Heres my code on action script:

var myCheckbox:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
    vbox.addChild(myCheckbox);

How to add click event on checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private function myCheckboxClicked(event:MouseEvent)
{
    // doStuff();
}

...

myCheckbox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myCheckboxClicked);
```

As long as it inherits EventDispatcher, you can attach a listener and it'll send events as normal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Upon implementing your solution, I've got this error.

1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type Function.

What is lacking? I put import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Comment: You can also be more specific and specify the return type of the function like so:

private function myCheckboxClicked(event:MouseEvent):void